# iOS7 auto layout, constraints, compression, content hugging

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, autolayout

I’m having bit of a tough time getting my head around auto layout, constraints, priorities, compression and content hugging.
I think I understand it but getting it to play nicely seems to be impossible.

I have this simple view, with 3 buttons and a label.
I want them to be able to adjust to fit the screen when the user orients the screen.

All the buttons are pinned to the leading and trailing superview. 
The top label’s top is pinned to the super view. The bottom button’s bottom is pinned to the superview.

There are vertical space constraints between the buttons.
I have tried varying priority levels for the compression of the buttons to get them to squeeze vertically for the horizontal view, but everything disappears off the screen.
Or one of the lower buttons appears above the upper buttons.

I am sure I am doing something quite simple to make these errors.

Would someone be able to offer me their 2 cents on how to fix this?

Many thanks for any help!

Merry xmas!

Adam

[image: vertical]

[image: horizontal]
[image]

**UPDATE - after "update all frames"**
It seems button 01 disappears when the view is rotated
[image]

**UPDATE #02 - almost working but not sure how **
Guys I seem to have managed to get it to work, but i'm not really sure how.
And it's not reliable - if I adjust the constraints between the label and the first button then the oriented view ends up scaling off out of the bounds of the screen.
I would assume that I could adjust that vertical constraint to be able to change that space, but it just makes a mess. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post your constraints and relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Pin the bottom button to the view controller's `bottomLayoutGuide`, not the `superview`. Do this by control-dragging from the bottom button to the Bottom Layout Guide in the scene's Document Outline.

Also, your interface objects are misaligned; that is, the frames don't match the constraints (or the constraints don't match the frames). That's why you see the dashed rectangular outlines. Go to the floating tool bar in the lower-right corner of the storyboard canvas and click on the "Resolve Auto Layout Issues". From there, either select "Update All Frames…" or "Update All Constraints".

I think the default values for compression resistance and content hugging priorities are adequate.

Comment: hey guys thanks for your help, i've have included an image with details of the constraints.

Comment: thanks i have tried your suggestions, the "Update All Constraints" doesn't have any effect - the lines remain dashed. Changing the pin to the bottomLayOutGuide isn't seem to have much effect either.

Comment: **UPDATE #02 - almost working but not sure how **
Guys I seem to have managed to get it to work, but i'm not really sure how.
And it's not reliable - if I adjust the constraints between the label and the first button then the oriented view ends up scaling off out of the bounds of the screen.
I would assume that I could adjust that vertical constraint to be able to change that space, but it just makes a mess.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the problem was, I'm seeing something very similar in my app.